# No property show found for type in spring data

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, eclipselink, spring-data

I have simple webapp in spring 3, jpa, eclipse link, spring data. When I try run it (on VMware server) I have got error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property show found for type foo.domain.Catalog
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="catalog")
@NamedQuery(name="Catalog.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Catalog c")
public class Catalog implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private String id;

private String adres;

private String opis;

private String tytul;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Category
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="cname", referencedColumnName="name")
private Category category;

public Catalog() {
}

public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAdres() {
    return this.adres;
}

public void setAdres(String adres) {
    this.adres = adres;
}

public String getOpis() {
    return this.opis;
}

public void setOpis(String opis) {
    this.opis = opis;
}

public String getTytul() {
    return this.tytul;
}

public void setTytul(String tytul) {
    this.tytul = tytul;
}

public Category getCategory() {
    return this.category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}
```

Interface repository:

```
public interface KatalogRepository extends JpaRepository<Catalog, Long>{

    @Query("select c from Catalog c left join fetch c.name")
    public List<Catalog> showAll();
    @Query("select c from Catalog c where c.tytul like %?1")
    public Catalog findByTytul(String tytul);
    @Query("select c from Category c")
    public List<Category> showAllCategory();
    @Query("select c from Category c where c.id =:id")
    public Category findCategoryById(Long id);

}
```

I tried many solutions but didn't help. Has someone got the similar problem? Thanks for help.

My dao class:

```
@Repository
public class KatalogDAO {

    @Autowired
    KatalogRepository katalogRepository;
    //@Autowired
    //CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    @Transactional
    public List<Catalog> showAllSites(){
        return katalogRepository.showAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveSite(Catalog catalog){
        katalogRepository.saveAndFlush(catalog);
    }
    @Transactional
    public Catalog showByTitle(String tytul){
        return katalogRepository.findByTytul(tytul);
    }
    @Transactional
    public List<Category> showAllCategory(){
        return katalogRepository.showAllCategory();
    }
    @Transactional
    public Category findCategoryById(Long id){
        return katalogRepository.findCategoryById(id);

    }
}
```

And endpoint:

```
@Component
public class CatalogEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    KatalogDAO katalogDAO;

    public List<Catalog> showAllSites(){
        return katalogDAO.showAllSites();

    }

    public void saveSite(Catalog catalog ){
        katalogDAO.saveSite(catalog);
    }

    public Catalog getByTitle(String tytul){
        return katalogDAO.showByTitle(tytul);
    }

    public List<Category> showCategory(){
        return katalogDAO.showAllCategory();
    }

    public Category findCategoryById(Long id){
        return katalogDAO.findCategoryById(id);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give us the code where you use the objects ? Or is there no code and its just the launching of this application that give this error ? Another thing, if you are using Spring Data JPA, you should extend CRUDRepository, and not use @Query for each request because it will generate these request automatically ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you wrote this query :

```
@Query("select c from Category c")
```

Which should be :

```
@Query("select * from Category c")
```

The error is probably caused by the Spring Data JPA framework, because if you give it a wrong request, it will probably try to generate a request based on the method name, but in this case, your method name should be "findAll". Moreover, the findAll() method is already given by the Spring Data JPA framework thanks to the CRUDRepository interface.